# How to get string from arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have problem with getting values from `ArrayList`. Eveyrhing I can do is get value like: `[Ljava.lang.string @....`

Can You help me please? I don't know what should be in the `mProductList.get(???)`. I want to have separated values from item clicked.

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {
private ListView lvProduct;
private ProductListAdapter adapter;
private List<Product> mProductList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    mProductList = new ArrayList<>();
    mProductList.add(new Product(1, "Product_1", "Price", "Description"));
    mProductList.add(new Product(2, "Product_2", "Price", "Description"));
    mProductList.add(new Product(3, "Product_3", "Price", "Description"));

    adapter = new ProductListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mProductList);
    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);

    lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BrowseProduct.class);
            newActivity.putExtra("1st column value", mProductList.get(???));
            newActivity.putExtra("2nd column value", mProductList.get(???));
            newActivity.putExtra("3rd column value", mProductList.get(???));
            newActivity.putExtra("4th column value", mProductList.get(???));
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: show your `Product`

Comment: to get the values you must have getters in your Product model class

Comment: Please tell us exactly what your problem is; that string `[Ljava.lang.string @....
` very much looks like you are calling toString on an **array** ... so step back; and create a real [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get position reference first and then fetch the value of that position from ArrayList

```
mProductList.get(position).getProductName();
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You should declare **Get and Set** Method in your **`Product`**  Class

```
 nowyEkran.putExtra("1st column value", mProductList.get(position).getProduct());
```

**Example**

```
        /**
         * Created by Intellij Amiyo  on 03-04-2017.
         */

        public class Product implements Serializable {

        public String product,price,description;
        int id;

        // Empty constructor
        public Product()
        {

        }

        // constructor
        public Product( int id,String product,String price,String description) {

            this.price = price;
            this.product = product;
            this.description = description;
            this.id=id;

        }

          public String getprice() {
            return this.price;
        }

        public void setprice(String price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
         public String getProduct() {
            return this.product;
        }

        public void setProduct(String product) {
            this.product = product;
        }
         public String getDescription() {
            return this.description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String product) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getID() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setID(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

}
```

Comment: getFirstColumn won't work until he has written this getter in Product model class

Comment: @AwaisMajeed I know . Its a example

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mProductList.get(position).getMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

this will get the index 0 1 2 of your array list,it will return the object

```
mProductList.get(0);
mProductList.get(1);
mProductList.get(2);
```

Comment: I am not sure if anybody really understands this question. The fact that we see 8 low quality answers within 10 minutes is a good indication that the question itself is low quality; and only works out as crap magnet. Sorry for the harsh wording; but that is exactly what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Put position in your Braces (). like below...

```
lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BrowseProduct.class);
            newActivity.putExtra("1st column value", mProductList.get(position));
            newActivity.putExtra("2nd column value", mProductList.get(position));
            newActivity.putExtra("3rd column value", mProductList.get(position));
            newActivity.putExtra("4th column value", mProductList.get(position));
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you...(:

Answer (score 0):

```
mProductList.get(position).price
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
```

You can get the clicked item position from the `int position` parameter of the callback method

Answer (score 0):

You already have a parameter called `position`. That will be the parameter of the `get`. However that will `return` a `Product` object and you will need to read the given member from there. Since you did not share the code of the `Product` `class` with us, we can only guess:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BrowseProduct.class);
        newActivity.putExtra("1st column value", mProductList.get(position).ID);
        newActivity.putExtra("2nd column value", mProductList.get(position).Name);
        newActivity.putExtra("3rd column value", mProductList.get(position).Price);
        newActivity.putExtra("4th column value", mProductList.get(position).Description);
        startActivity(newActivity);
    }
```

Comment: unless the access specifier of ID, Name, Price and Description is not private

Comment: @AwaisMajeed that's right. This is why I have written that in lack of knowledge about the Product class we can only guess.